# How to identify an android app is native or hybrid (phonegap)

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I hired one guy to develop android/ios application for my site. I want it as native, but i want to check if the developer used phonegap to create this application. Can i identify that without checking the source code ?

Comment: If the android app looks like an iOS app, that's your clue. But since you hired the fellow, the source code should be yours.

Comment: Does he has access to your server? If not, the app will be probably just a webview

Comment: @jcesarmobile i'm providing the webservices for the app.

Comment: @savepopulation he gave 2 separate quote for native and phonegap. I choose native, so i want to make sure he's not using phonegap. I'm paying more money for the native devl.

Comment: With Android, Go to Developer Options > Debug GPU overdraw > Show Overdraw Areas. After that go to the desired app, if areas have different colors on each components tgen it is a native app. If you see app's components as normal then it is a hybrid app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Answer consists of looking at the source code but you don't need direct access to it.*

You could find out by simply uncompressing the .apk or .ipa installation file for android or ios respectively (like you would any zip file). If it's a phonegap app you will find a /www/ folder with html/css/js files, one which should be named cordova.js or phonegap.js.